# Strange navbar effect when blurred on iOS

Tags: html, css, blur, mobile-website

I'm getting a very strange effect only on iOS devices (regardless of the browser) when I try to apply blur to my navbar.

On safari on iOS:

[image]

On Chrome on iOS:

[image]

On Chrome on Android it looks fine:

[image]

On emulator it looks fine too:

[image]

The way I apply the blur to the navbar is as follows:

```
.navbar-item {
     -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
     backdrop-filter: blur(8px)
}
```

Comment: Apply it to the parent instead of the individual items and should get the uniformity you're after (also will cause less repaint(s) and easier on the compositor). Would suggest a parent pseudo element for the effect so it doesn't potentially effect children.

Comment: @ChrisW. Resolved! A thousand thanks! Out of curiosity: why such behavior occurs on iOS and not on Android?

Comment: Sorry I've never taken the time to look into specifically why, maybe a future reader will enlighten us both? Would guess it's just in how the gaussian effect is calc'd based on the element it's applied to in relation to it's background layer when getting composited, but that's just a guess ¯\_(ツ)_/¯